# Which JavaScript carousel zooms blocks from the playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw a carousel/slider for displaying featured content a while ago that does something that most don't. It started fairly simply, with the top feature large, and a playlist to the side of other featured stories:

[image: Initial state]

Feature 1 then began to slide towards the bottom right, while feature 2 moved to occupy the main slot, and the previews of features 3 and 4 moved up:

[image: Start of slide]
[image: End of slide]
[image: Final state]

The slider had now completed a whole swap, and was ready to do the same thing with feature 3.

My Google-fu seems to be lacking in finding this again; does anyone know of this slider? I think it was based on one of the frameworks, but I'm not sure whether it was jQuery or one of the others.